# XP disk check runs every time I boot

Tags: boot, windows-xp, check-disk

Every time I boot my computer XP checks my backup partition (it is NTFS) for errors, this has become really annoying because my computer is old-ish (5+ years) and I don't leave it on like I used to.

Is there any way I can disable the disk check, or solve the problem?

Comment: Could be an indication of a failing disk.

Comment: I have checked the drive, and the partitions for errors with defraggler and it doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this from the command line (I'm assuming drive C; adjust as appropriate):

```
chkntfs /x c:

/X  Excludes a drive from the default boot-time check.  Excluded
    drives are not accumulated between command invocations.
```

Use this to see if a drive needs to be checked or is configured to be checked on next boot:

```
chkntfs c:
```

Comment: Thanks, I did what you say and it doesn't check the disk at start up any more.