# Why does Windows run CHKDSK on every boot?

Tags: windows-xp, chkdsk

Every time I turn on my PC, I get the following message:

```
Checking file system on E:
The type of the file systen is NTFS.
One of your disks need to be checked for consistency. You may cancel the disk check, but it is strongly recommended that you continue.
Windows will now check the disk.

CHKDSK is verifying files (stage 1 of 3)... 0 percent completed
```

I allow CHKDSK to to complete, but Windows does not load. This message appears every time I boot my computer.

Could someone explain me why this message appears and what I should do to make it disappear?

Comment: possible duplicate of [XP disk check runs every time I boot](http://superuser.com/questions/164240/xp-disk-check-runs-every-time-i-boot)

Comment: @hims056 That question refers to a system that is working. The OP has stated that chkdsk completes but Windows does not load.

Answer (score 7):

When you schedule a check disk, an entry is added to the registry - for some reason, it's not being cleared.

1. Run the Registry Editor (Click Start, Run and type `regedit` then press OK).
2. Locate `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager`
3. Change the `BootExecute` entry from:
   `autocheck autochk * /r\DosDevice\C:`
   to:
   `autocheck autochk *`

Source:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/158675

Comment: I go step by step in those article, but in my Registry Editor BootExecute already has value autocheck autochk * not like autochk * /r\DosDevice\C:

Comment: If the CHKDSK were scheduled, I believe the message would say that. This seems to be a problem with the HDD itself, rather than a scheduled disk check not being cleared.

Comment: Yes, it does. In that case, I would suggest checking it with http://www.acronis.co.uk/homecomputing/products/drive-monitor/

Answer (score 6):

If you have not asked for a chkdsk to be carried out, the autocheck will be carried out if the disk's "dirty bit" is set. This will be set if Windows is not shut down correctly, file changes have not completed or the disk is corrupted. It may indicate the disk is about to fail. For an external disk, it may indicate it was removed without using the 'safely remove hardware' function.

The [fsutil](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/fsutil_dirty.mspx?mfr=true) command can be used to check the status of the dirty bit.  Open a command prompt with admin rights and type:

```
fsutil dirty query D:
```

(Replace `D:` with the letter of the drive you are having issues with.)

Comment: I check my hard disk, it is dirty - what should I do to correct this?

Comment: Try running `chkdsk /f e:` or `chkdsk /f /r e:` manually. If the dirty bit is still set after the next reboot, the system probably cannot umount the volume on shutdown. Check the `eventlog` for pointers if that's the case

Comment: I get such message after executing command chkdsk /f e:     E:\Documents and Settings\Consultant>chkdsk /f /r e:
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Cannot lock current drive.

Chkdsk cannot run because the volume is in use by another
process.  Would you like to schedule this volume to be
checked the next time the system restarts? (Y/N) n

Comment: @khris That's normal. You can only run chkdsk on the system drive at boot.

Comment: ok, I try once again: 1) enter chkd /f /r in cmd 2) press y after message that drive can't be locked 3)restart my pc - the same message (as in my parent question) 4) allowfile verifying. In result I get message thet verifying is complite on blue screen and windows do nnot load and I can't execute any command - just shut down os pressing button on keyboard.

Comment: So how do you get Windows running? Is this what happens? 1.You power up, 2. the chkdsk dialog appears and you allow it to run and apparently complete, 3. the system locks without starting Windows 4. you hold the power button down to force a shutdown, 5. you power on and Windows starts up normally.

Comment: 5. I power on and dialog appears, but I do not allow it to verify disk, so after that windows starts.

Comment: Acctualy it is not a big problem - I could normaly work with my pc, but every time I restart windows appears that dialog, I won't this happen

Comment: You should run the manufacturer's diagnostics on the disk. It may be about to fail.

Answer (score 3):

1. Click on your start menu and open the run dialog.
2. Type `cmd` and return
3. Next type `fsutil dirty query D:` (replace `D:` with your drive letter)

[image: fsutil dirty query]

If the return message indicates that the volume is dirty then continue with these steps:

5. Next type `chkdsk D: /f /x`
6. After that finshes repeat step 3 to determine if dirty bit has been removed.
7. If it is no longer dirty then reboot and you should notice no more
   chkdisk.

[Source of Information](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/chkdsk-runs-every-time-boot-t72388.html)

Comment: it doesn't help - see earlier comments

Answer (score 0):

I had similar symptoms on my laptop as you and:

```
chkntfs /X E:
```

Helped me (I didn't expect this).

Also [try](http://www.technize.info/check-disk-chkdsk-runs-every-time-windows-starts/) change **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager** key **BootExecute** to:

```
autocheck autochk /k:E *
```

Answer (score 0):

***A cause example:***
*In my case, Check-disk (at boot) is (re)produced from a "bad" misconfigurated **custom shutdown batch**|command, which (accidentally) makes the system thinks the shutdown was "Unexpected" (not normaly shutted) and sets the disk-check . - IF the "dirty" disk is the windows disk(C:) must be dismounted first - but, as the disk is in use by the system, sets an auto chkdsk at the next boot.*

> *Cause more explanation:*
>
> *I have set a "Run-on-idle-time" 'scheduled task' which after (1hour) pointed idle time expiration, triggers a custom `HurryCleanNShutDown.bat`|cmd program. So, the program eg. starts the 'cleans', waits to finish and then shuts down (forced) the Computer.
> Even if I tried many shutdown switch(es) (`/d`) combinations (`SHUTDOWN.exe /s /t 60 /f /d p:0:0 /c "PC shutting down... (in 1 minute)"` or even with `chkNTFS /x c:`) the computer keeps giving the same problem Only IF Shutting Down triggered by this batch|program.*

***Note that if any third program could not use proper shutdown command syntax could reason this false chkDSK error.***

***Use of ShutDown:** (**`shutdown /?`**)

 - **I**f **`shutdown`** is not accompanied by the required `/d`'switch' with the `p|u:xx:yy` 'reason code', then the system considers this 'Shutdown'`shutdown /s` (or 'Reboot'`shutdown /r`) as "**Unexpected**" (not normaly shutted).

 - If the above happens, the system points|flags the disc as "**dirty**" (bit) in the registry and promts for disk-check **or** (if it's current System's drive[C:] in use), sets an auto chkdsk (`chkDSK C: /f ... /x`) at the next boot (because System drive must dismount first).

 - After successful "chkDSK" the System will return to normal `chkNTFS /d` ---> [RegEdit: BootExecute value data: "autocheck autochk *"].*

***Fixes:***


***Suggested to use the "Command Prompt"*** *(run as admin)* ***instead of "Registry Editor".***

 *It is much easier to use `chkNTFS` command which automatically changes the*

 ---> "BootExecute REG_MULTI_SZ" data value. (examples following below)

 *Also, if computer do not boot,*

***chkDSK and chkNTFS commands can be run from Recovery Console too.***

 */!\ Warning: command 'switches' differs a bit when you run from Recovery.*

 *Tip: `chkntfs /?` | `chkdsk /?` to saw the use of.*

- How to **Check if a disk is pointed as "dirty":**

  **`fsutil dirty query c:`**  *("c:" is disk letter)*
- How to **Forced Check Disk on (E:) disk:**

  **`chkNTFS /c E:`**  *("E:" is disk letter)*

   ---> [RegEdit: BootExecute value data: "autocheck autochk /m ??\E:"]
- How to **Cancel Check on next boot:**
  *(Excludes a drive from the default boot-time check.)*

  **`chkNTFS /x c:`**  *("c:" is disk letter)*

   ---> [RegEdit: BootExecute value data: "autocheck autochk /k:C"]
- How to **Restore Defaults:** *(Restores the machine to the default behavior:

   all drives are checked at boot time and chkdsk is run on those that are
  dirty.)*

  **`chkNTFS /d`** ---> [RegEdit: BootExecute value data: **"autocheck autochk *"**]


   *(i) Registry key address:*
  **[`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\BootExecute`]**

   *BootExecute REG_MULTI_SZ (multi-string value)*.

***Here is almost everything about:*** *by Richard John Eaton*

[https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/.../force-autochk-at-every-boot-up](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d90a4d12-6050-4c26-9d6b-c10d3a4ca2c6/force-autochk-at-every-boot-up?forum=embeddedwindowseefs)